# How to create an invisible square inside a div with text?

Tags: html, css

I need to reproduce the image below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh8be.png]

The image in the center is my background. In my first div I've got some text. Over this div I need maybe an other div that hides a part of the div with the text so I can see the background of my page. Is there anyway I can have this invisible square in the middle of my div in CSS ?

The reason I need this behaviour is because I'm using the parallax scrolling effect.

Comment: requiring people to download random files is scary as hell. please just show the picture, or even better, create a jsFiddle of the code.

Comment: I don;t understand your question. Can you explain what it is you want to create?

Comment: You want a block of text which you will format and style as you see fit.  You then want to overlay over this block an image which is also the background image behind the block of text? Please confirm.

Comment: Will the background expand beyond the text?

Comment: Just to clarify your question:  you want to create a text block which has a "hole" in it, so that the background shows through?

Comment: In my first div I've got some text. Over this div I need maybe an other div that hides a part of the div with the text so I can see the background of my page.

Comment: What you're looking for is a *clipping mask* (see:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in webkit, you can use a mask:

```
#background, #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}


#background {
    background: url("yourimage");
}

#overlay {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-mask-position: 0px 0px;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 66%), 
                        linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 33%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 66%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 66%); 
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/jakwy/)

I have set the background of the overlay with a little alpha to show that the background div is stiil there, just set it to white in real code.

Answer (score 1):

`position:absolute; left: something; top: something; z-index: 2;`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a transparent image for this. This will create a 'window' to expose your background. I will also enable your text to wrap around it as apposed to cover it.

Comment: I think the OP does not want the text to wrap around it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#text-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image-container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="text-container">
    <p>Background text here</p>
    <div id="image-container">
        <img src="picture.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The reason for specifying the top and left at 50% is so that the image box will be 50% from the top and left of the parent div. This applies to the top and left edges of the image box though, so it ends up not being quite centered. Setting the margins to - 1/2 the width and hight offsets them so that the box is properly centered.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p3gJg/) is a link to a working fiddle

Comment: OP wanted the page background to show through, not for the square to be colored.

Comment: The color is just there because I didn't include an image. All he'd do is just not set a background color on `#image-container`

Comment: If he wants the background text to be slightly visible under the floating image, he would just use a semi-transparent gif or png

Comment: He wants the PAGE background to show through, though.  Not the text.

Comment: I just updated my question with the parallax, this is why I really need to see the background behind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do in pure CSS is to place an image on top of your text which exactly matches your background image. It would not be a true hole, just an illusion.